# Adding multiple key value pairs to a python dictionary and then checking for duplicate values

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I am new to python and I am reading a line from a gzip file -

```py
('ABC', 'MUMBAI', None, None, '123', None, None) xx 1 1191

('ABC', 'MUMBAI', None, None, '123', None, None) xx 1 1000
```

There are these 4 values and out of which I have to check if combination of 1st and 3rd elements are already present. If present, we have to sum the 4th element and insert it in Postgres DB.

output -

```
('ABC', 'MUMBAI', None, None, '123', None, None) xx 1 2191
```

when I am inserting these rows in a Postgres db which has a unique constraint for 1st attribute, 2nd attribute, 3rd attribute, and date. I get "duplicate key value violates unique constraint".

I tried creating a dictionary and updating it if duplicate records are found but i am not able to get through. I don't want to add another loop and traverse the whole gzip file. Is there any optimized solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after taking a clue from answer by @michaeldel -

```
sql_query_template = "INSERT INTO product_data.data VALUES ( (%s) , (%s) , %s , '%s' , %d );"
master_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)
imported_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)
for line in self.gziplines(`enter code here`filename):
    line=line.replace("\0", " ")
    product, category, attribute, value = self.split_line(line)
    key = (product, attribute)
    if key not in master_dict:
        master_dict[key] = value
    else:
        master_dict[key] += value
for line in self.gziplines(filename):
    line=line.replace("\0", " ")
    if product[0] != None and key not in imported_dict:
       sql_query = sql_query_template % (category, product, attribute, date, master_dict.get(key))
       cur.execute(sql_query)
       imported_dict[key] = master_dict.get(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering `records` an iterable of your data, for instance like this

```python
records = [
    (('ABC', 'MUMBAI', None, None, '123', None, None), xx, 1, 1191),
    (('ABC', 'MUMBAI', None, None, '123', None, None), xx, 1, 1000),
    ...
]
```

Your problem can be solved like so

```python
import collections

sums = collections.defaultdict(int)

for record in records:
    key = (record[0], record[2])  # combination of first and third element
    sums[key] += record[3]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It helps but it returns a int dictionary - 
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {(('ABC', 'MUMBAI', None, None, '123', None, None), 1): 1191})

while i need to traverse the lines in a zip ( for line in self.gziplines(filename))
i need a line row and not a dictionary.

Comment: Just iterate over that dictionary and print items to get the output you want